# Import ForeignKey values by ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to import a `ForeignKey` values using `ComboBox`, but the `ComboBox` loads `string` values and the `ForeignKey` type is `int`,I tried to convert `ToString()`,then I got error:

> "The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable property or indexer"

```
            ShippingDocumentDataClassesDataContext dc = new ShippingDocumentDataClassesDataContext();
        t_tracking newInvoice = new t_tracking();

        newInvoice.SupplierId.ToString() = comboBox1.Text;

        dc.t_trackings.InsertOnSubmit(newInvoice);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
newInvoice.SupplierId.ToString() = comboBox1.Text;
```

you are trying to assign value to method call.

Instead this line should be:

```
newInvoice.SupplierId = Int32.Parse(comboBox1.Text);
```

or safer way:

```
int id = 0;

if (Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.Text, out id))
{
    //we get valid integer from combobox
    newInvoice.SupplierId = id;

    dc.t_trackings.InsertOnSubmit(newInvoice);
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
else
{
    //wrong value handling code goes here
}
```